# Multithreaded WebClient requests return error - System.Net.WebException

Tags: c#, multithreading, webclient

I have 5000+ pages I want to download using `WebClient`. Since I want that done as fast as possible I am trying to use multithreading (using `BlockingCollection` in my case), but the program always seems to be crashing after a while with error - "System.Net.WebException". If I add some `Thread.Sleep(3000)` delay it slows down my download process and it returns the error after a little more time.

It usually takes about 2-3 seconds to download one page.

Normally, I would guess that there is a problem with my `BlockingCollection`, but it works fine with other tasks, so I am pretty sure that something has to be wrong with my `WebClient` requests. I think there might be some kind of overlapping between the separate `WebClients`, but that's just guessing.

```
        Multithreading multiThread = new Multithreading(5); 
        for(int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= 5181; pageNumber++)
        {
            multiThread.EnqueueTask(new Action(() => //add task ("scrape the trader") to the multithread queue
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFile("http://example.com/page=" + pageNumber.ToString(), @"C:\mypages\page " + pageNumber.ToString() + ".html");
                } 
            }));
            //I put the Thread.Sleep(123) delay here
        }
```

If I add a smaller delay (`Thread.Sleep(100)` for example) it works fine, but then I end up scraping `Page # *whatever pageNumber's value is at the moment*`, not in order as it usually does.

Here is my `BlockingCollection` (I think I got this code from stackoverflow):

```
class Multithreading : IDisposable
{
      BlockingCollection<Action> _taskQ = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

      public Multithreading(int workerCount)
      {
        // Create and start a separate Task for each consumer:
        for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
          Task.Factory.StartNew (Consume);
      }

      public void Dispose() { _taskQ.CompleteAdding(); }

      public void EnqueueTask (Action action) { _taskQ.Add (action); }

      void Consume()
      {
        // This sequence that we’re enumerating will block when no elements
        // are available and will end when CompleteAdding is called. 
        foreach (Action action in _taskQ.GetConsumingEnumerable())
          action();     // Perform task.
      }
}
```

I also tried putting everything into endless `while` loop and handling the error using `try...catch` statements, but apparently it does not return the error immediately, but after a while (not sure when).

Here is the whole exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
```

Comment: Show us the stacktrace

Comment: If you want to download files async why not using the client.DownloadFileAsync operation?

Comment: whats in the exception?

Comment: @Stefan, I have added the whole exception at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class is not guaranteed to be thread safe. from MSDN:

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe

**Update**

Use one `HttpWebRequest` for each request that you make. If you make a lot of requests to different web sites it doesn't matter if you use `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`.

If you do a lot of requests to the same web site it is still not as inefficient as it seems. `HttpWebRequest` reuse connections (it's hidden underneath the hood). Microsoft uses something called service points and you can access them through the [HttpWebRequest.ServicePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.servicepoint.aspx) property. If you click on the property definition you come to the `ServicePoint` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.aspx) where you can fine tune the number of connections per web site etc.