# C# - Multi-Threading with WebClient

Tags: c#, multithreading, web

I wanted to ask if it's possible to do multi-threading with WebClient?

```
Parallel.ForEach(Keywords, s =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Pages; i++)
            {
                string url = URLdownloader.DownloadString("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + s + "&first=" + i + "0");
                MatchCollection urlCollection = Regex.Matches(url.ToString(), @"(\Whttp:\/\W[a-z./?=A-Z0-9&-]+)");
                foreach (Match m in urlCollection)
                {
                    urlsdownload.Add(m.ToString().Replace(@"""", ""));
                    urlsdownload = urlsdownload.Distinct().ToList();
                    File.WriteAllLines(
                        @"C:\Users\username\Desktop\DorkWorker\URLparser\Bing.txt".Replace("username",
                            Environment.UserName), urlsdownload);
                }
            }
        });
```

let's say I have 100 URLs, instead of checking 1 by 1, how is it possible to check 10 at the same time? or 5?

Comment: Have you tried `Parallel.ForEach()`?

Comment: Too many approaches, did you actually try anything? Like using `Task.WhenAll` or `Parallel.ForEach`?

Comment: tried parallel.foreach, and it didn't work, the program crashed

Comment: What is URLDownloader? Anyway, WebClient is not thread-safe (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608774/multithreaded-webclient-requests-return-error-system-net-webexception). You should use HttpClient, which is.

Comment: There are an issue with `File.WriteAllLines` too.

Comment: @ZorgoZ What? Who told you that HttpClient is thread-safe? That's certainly not true (try it if you want) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Well, that statement is over-simplified but not when applied to the original question. I am using a single instance over multiple threads with no issues. But one has to take things into consideration: http://www.michaeltaylorp3.net/httpclient-is-it-really-thread-safe/

Comment: Consider reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/how-to-make-multiple-web-requests-in-parallel-by-using-async-and-await . Also consider setting `DefaultConnectionLimit` (otherwise you will be limited to very few parallel downloads) - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2009/05/20/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `DownloadStringAsync()` instead of `DownloadString`:
int curDownload = 0;
Imagining that your urls are in a string array named `DownloadUrls`:

```
WebClient[] wc = new WebClient[10];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
   wc[i] = new WebClient();
   wc[i].DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) => 
   {
         if(curDownload<DownloadUrls.Length-1)
         (WebClient(s)).DownloadStringAsync(DownloadUrls[curDownload++]);
   };
if(curDownload<DownloadUrls.Length-1)
wc[i].DownloadStringAsync(DownloadUrls[curDownload++]);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain what it does? (s, e) make me confused

Comment: `DownloadStringAsync` starts the download in another thread and just will raise the event `DownloadStringCompleted` which in there you can start the next download, so in here we have 10 webclients, each grabs a url to download for example `curDownload` will be 9, then the first download that completed, downloadstringcompleted event of that webclient will fire so, you can download next, `DownloadUrls[curDownload++]` that in this example would be 10

Comment: Thank you, I will try it :)

Comment: if you can implement it, it will work, I have done it hundreds of times.