# .NET Core: Concurrency defect in WebClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I use this code to hammer on a system:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
int i = 0;
int limit = 10000;
long start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:h:mm:ss.fffffff} : " + ++i);
    client.DownloadString("https://localhost:44305/");
} while (i < limit);

Console.WriteLine(limit + " requests in " + new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - start) + " (" + ((DateTime.Now.Ticks - start)/limit)/1000 + " ms/request)");
```

Sometimes it works. Sometimes I get an exception (iteration number seems random):

```
System.Net.WebException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/n
etwork address/port) is normally permitted.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10048): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at CommandName.ThingDoer.DoThing(IRepository repository) in C:\data\OneDrive\source\rider\ContentstackPlaygroundTemplates\cstest\ThingDoer.cs:line 31
   at CommandName.Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Main>b__0() in C:\data\OneDrive\source\rider\ContentstackPlaygroundTemplates\cstest\Program.cs:line 65
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplicationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<OnExecute>b__0()
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.<>c__DisplayClass144_0.<OnExecute>b__0(CancellationToken _)
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at CommandName.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\data\OneDrive\source\rider\ContentstackPlaygroundTemplates\cstest\Program.cs:line 70 : Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

Could this be a concurrency defect in WebClient, am I doing something wrong, or what could be the explanation?

System.Web.Client 4.0.2.0, .NETCoreApp v3.0.3

Comment: Use `HttpClient` instead. Using `WebClient` in new development is discouraged and it is not guaranteed to be thread-safe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608774/multithreaded-webclient-requests-return-error-system-net-webexception

Comment: The ServicePointManager controls how many active connections are allowed. It could be that you are sometimes overwhelming its queue and sometimes not. You could see if setting its DefaultConnectionLimit to at least 10000 works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I did not try with ServicePointManager because HttpClient seemed to solve the issue. This seems to work now.

```
private void McHammer()
{
    int i = 0;
    int limit = 1000;
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    do
    {
        try
        {
            if (i % 100 == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("#");
            }

            string discard = httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:5001/").Result;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.GetType() + " : " + ex.Message);
            // break on first error
            limit = 0;
        }
    } while (i++ < limit);

        TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - start.Ticks);
        double ms = timeSpan.Ticks / 10000;
        double msPerRequest = ms / --i;
        double requestPerSec = i / ms;
        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0} : {1} requests in {2}ms ({3} ~ms/request; ~{4} request/sec)",
            this,
            i,
            ms,
            Math.Round(msPerRequest * 1000)/1000,
            Math.Round(requestPerSec * 1000));
}
```